The étale fundamental group of an DM stack acting on a locally constant sheaf
Let $W$ be a connected and separated Deligne-Mumford stack  of finite type  over an algebraically closed field $k$, and $w\in W$ a geometric point. Consider the étale fundamental group $\pi_1^{ét}(W,w)$, and   $M$ a finite type and locally constant sheaf of $\Lambda-$modules on $W_{ét}$ (here $\Lambda$ is a ring)
In the article "THE TROPICALIZATION OF THE MODULI SPACE OF CURVES"
at some point (page 790) there is an statement which say that the étale fundamental group $\pi_1^{ét}(W,w)$ acts in a natural way on the stalk $M_w$. If such sheaf takes values in the category of finite sets, I know that this action is natural. I tried to mimic the proof in the case of schemes See
but fixing  an element $\sigma$ of the fundamental group, and considering a tuple $(Y,y,t)$  of $M_w$, where $t \in M(Y \to W)$, I might think that the natural action of $\sigma$ "could be" over the geometric point $y$, but I didn't see a natural manner to define it.
Does anyone know how this "natural action" is defined?


The discussion in your stacks project link also includes a link to this, which defines the action of the absolute Galois group of the generic point on the stalk. Your linked article then proves that this action factors through $\pi_1$. Also, your last sentence is doubled (I think?)

I thought about this, and there are several slightly details to take in account: Points on a stack is class. Therefore, I was thinking to replace it by residual gerbes. You can consider the generic point of an stack, which is a residual gerbe. So, you can take the field associated  (call it $\eta=Spec\ \ k$) fix it, you can induce  $\pi_1^{ét}(\eta,\overline{\eta})\to \pi_1^{ét}(W,\overline{\eta})$. The idea that I have in mind is to proof that this map is surjective. One way is to proof that $ \pi_1^{ét}(U,\eta)\to  \pi_1^{ét}(W,\eta)$ for every open substack, but at this point I get stuck.
